Why Spring Boot Console Application using RestClient does not recognize MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter
Creating new SpringBoot Console application which doesn't require a web server but will execute a one time job which calls couple of rest end points.
In application.yml have below:
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: NONE

In pom, have web starter dependency since using RestTemplate and some others:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.4</version>
</dependency>

When the code runs, can check that RestTemplate has MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter in its list for sure.
But in my HttpClient Code when I use below code it errors out:
@Override
public ArchivalResponse archiveResult(String username, String password, ArchivalPayload archivalPayload) {
    ResponseEntity<ArchivalResponse> response;
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    //headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[] { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON }));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);
    //String json ="<manually created json same as archivalPayload>";
    HttpEntity<ArchivalPayload> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(archivalPayload, headers);
    URI uri = Utils.generateURI(hostname, ARCHIVE_API);
    try {
        response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, ArchivalPayload.class);               
    } catch (Exception ex) { //TODO: improve
        System.out.println("Exception while calling archive API");
        throw ex;
    }
    return response.getBody();
}

Throws Error:
RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for <class name> and content type "application/json"

However for time being I am using String instead of relying on auto-conversion to json and it works fine:
@Override
public String archiveResult(String username, String password, ArchivalPayload archivalPayload) {
    ResponseEntity<String> response;
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    //headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[] { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON }));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);
    String json ="<manually created json same as archivalPayload>";
    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(json, headers);
    URI uri = Utils.generateURI(hostname, ARCHIVE_API);
    try {
        response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);               
    } catch (Exception ex) { //TODO: improve
        System.out.println("Exception while calling archive API");
        throw ex;
    }
    return response;
}

Can anyone please let me know why it doesnt work. Note its not a web application.
